# How do you loop through a 2D array with other arrays

Tags: python

```
#Array
Days = ["Mon 1","Tue 1","Wed 1","Thu 1","Fri 1",
        "Mon 2","Tue 2","Wed 2","Thu 2","Fri 2",
        "Mon 3","Tue 3","Wed 3" ,"Thu 3","Fri 3",
        "Mon 4","Tue 4","Wed 4","Thu 4","Fri 4"]
Route = ["Bus A","Bus B","Bus C","Bus D","Bus E","Bus F"]

            #A #B  #C  #D  #E  #F
BusData = [[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

For this code, I would like to ask the user to input a value for each day in a route and store that information in BusData.The array should have information like this:

BusData = [[Bus A days], [Bus B Days],[Bus C Days], [Bus D Days], [Bus E days],  [Bus F Days]

I was thinking of using something like a for loop

Comment: What is [Bus A days] ? Is that all days from Days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and can convert it into lists of list accordingly.

```
Days = ["Mon 1","Tue 1","Wed 1","Thu 1","Fri 1",
        "Mon 2","Tue 2","Wed 2","Thu 2","Fri 2",
        "Mon 3","Tue 3","Wed 3" ,"Thu 3","Fri 3",
        "Mon 4","Tue 4","Wed 4","Thu 4","Fri 4"]

Route = ["Bus A","Bus B","Bus C","Bus D","Bus E","Bus F"]

BusData={"Bus A":[],"Bus B":[],"Bus C":[],"Bus D":[],"Bus E":[],"Bus F":[]}

for i in Days:
    userInput=input() #type of bus for that particular day 

    BusData[userInput].append(i)

print(BusData)
```